# Trigger event on Zend Framework 2 view/layout

Tags: events, zend-framework2

There is any way to trigger an event like wordpress on views/layouts? What i need is something like this:

index.phtml:

```
<?php $this->triggerEvent('before_navigation', $params, $order); ?>
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu() ?>
<?php $this->triggerEvent('after_navigation', $params, $order); ?>
```

Then, any module can be capable to attach a listener with the name of the event and do what the want sorted by $order

Comment: I would say you should not do this inside your layouts. Instead you could make a `NavigationService` (or refactor the existing `'navigation'` service that you are using) where you add an `EventManager` to trigger those pre and post events.

Comment: You may not explain enough. What I need is to define sections in the templates so that each module that is created can use those sections to display their own content without having to modify the layout. Not only on navigation.